# Redux.js: catching malformed actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a best practice/recommended way to assert that a redux action is well-formed?  I am a fairly noobish JavaScript programmer (coming at it from 20 years of C++/Java/C#) and thrown off by the lack of strong typing.

Specifically the use case I am trying to address is:

1.using the React + Redux "ToDo" app (http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html)

2.using action creator:

```
export function toggleTodo(index) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
}
```

3.with reducer code snippet:

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  if (state.id !== action.id) {
    return state
  }
```

Notice that **index** and **id** don't match up.  However, they should have - it was a bug. This took me 30 minutes to diagnose, and I can only imagine for larger apps.

Comment: I created a GitHub repo with a redux-action-validator base class. The README has more info about implementation: https://github.com/michael-martin-al/redux-action-validator

Comment: That's pretty cool!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a Class that represents an Action type, and then letting it handle the validation, like so...

```
class ToggleAction {
   constructor(o) {
     if (
       typeof o === 'object' &&
       typeof o.type === 'string' &&
       typeof o.id === 'number'
     ) {
       this.type = "TOGGLE_TODO"; 
       this.id = o.id
     } else {
       throw new Error('Invalid ToggleAction');
     }
   }

   toObject() {
     return { type: this.type, id: this.id };
   }
}
```

And then you could use it like this in the action creator...

```
export function toggleTodo(index) {
  return new ToggleAction({ id: index }).toObject();
}
```

And like this in the reducer...

```
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  const toggleAction = new ToggleAction(action)
  if (state.id !== toggleAction.id) {
    return state
  }
```

If all of that works out well, you could create an ActionFactory that generated ActionType classes.

**EDIT:** I created an [npm module](https://github.com/michael-martin-al/redux-action-validator) called `redux-action-validator` with a README describing how to install and use it.